# Can't parse string "N/A" from .XLSX in Python 2.7 with pandas

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, pandas, getattr

I've got a large Excel spreadsheet that I'm trying to parse into Python2.7 and pandas 0.19.1 to insert the data into a MySQL database. As part of this, some of the cells contain the string "N/A". Unfortunately, pandas doesn't seem to be able to parse "N/A", instead it imports nan. When including single or double quotation marks around the string, pandas imports it as ""N/A"" and 'N/A' respectively, and does not match my data.

Is there any way to read the string "N/A" without modifying the existing data?

MWE follows, including link to test data file on GitHub:

```
import pandas as pd
loadData = pd.ExcelFile("testData.xlsx")
testData = loadData.parse("Sheet1")

for row in testData.itertuples(index=True, name='testTuple'):     
    if getattr(row, "Value") == "N/A":
        print(row)
```

Link to test data file: https://github.com/quacksawbones/testData/blob/master/testData.xlsx

(NB: First question on StackOverflow. Please let me know if I've missed anything or need more information)

Answer (score 1):

According to my understand of your question you want to replace NaN with "N/A", If you want this you can use fillna method,

```
df=df.fillna('N/A')
```

If this is not you required explain me clearly what you want....

Comment: Hi Mohamed,

I was hoping to be able to read "N/A" directly from my spreadsheet and have it interpreted as a string "N/A" rather than NaN. But I think I could use this as a workaround. Thanks mate :)